# How to load supervised data into MLContext object

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

**My Situation**
I am attempting to create a neural network that classifies two types of signals (yes or no essentially) using ML.net. I have one set of data that maps to no and another that will map to yes. I hope to train the network with this data.

**My Problem**
Since my training data is supervised (I know the desired output), how do I "tell" the `LoadFromTextFile` function that all that data should map to "yes" (or 1 it doesn't matter)

> **My Question**
> In short, how do you train a network with supervised data(I know the desired output of my training data) in ML.Net?

My Data Model:

```
public class Analog
{
    [LoadColumn(0, Global.SAMPLE_SIZE - 1)]
    [VectorType(Global.SAMPLE_SIZE)]
    public float[] DiscreteSignal { get; set; }
}
```

Loading code:

```
//Create MLContext
static MLContext mCont = new MLContext();

//Load Data
IDataView data = mCont.Data.LoadFromTextFile<Analog>("myYesSignalData.csv", separatorChar: ',', hasHeader: false);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ML.NET has support for loading multiple datasets into one `IDataView`, by using the `MultiFileSource` class:

```
var loader = mCont.Data.LoadFromTextFile<Analog>(separatorChar: ',', hasHeader: false);
IDataView data = loader.Load(new MultiFileSource("myYesSignalData.csv", "myNoSignalData.csv"));
```

However, I currently see no way to let the trainer know which examples are positive and which are negative other than to add a label column to both files: in the "yes" file add an all-ones column and in the "no" file add an all-zeros column. Then define the `Analog` class this way:

```
public class Analog
{
    [LoadColumn(0, Global.SAMPLE_SIZE - 1)]
    [VectorType(Global.SAMPLE_SIZE)]
    public float[] DiscreteSignal { get; set; }

    [LoadColumn(Global.SAMPLE_SIZE)]
    public float Label { get; set; }
}
```

Adding the label column can be done with a simple C# program, such as this:

```
public class AnalogNoLabel
{
    [LoadColumn(0, Global.SAMPLE_SIZE - 1)]
    [VectorType(Global.SAMPLE_SIZE)]
    public float[] DiscreteSignal { get; set; }
}

public void AddLabel(MLContext mCont)
{
    IDataView data = mCont.Data.LoadFromTextFile<AnalogNoLabel>("myYesSignalData.csv", separatorChar: ',', hasHeader: false);
    var pipeline = mCont.Transforms.CustomMapping<AnalogNoLabel, Analog>((input, output) => {
        output.DiscreteSignal = input.DiscreteSignal;
        output.Label = 1;
    }, contractName: null);
    IDataView dataWithLabel = pipeline.Fit(data).Transform(data);
    using (var stream = new FileStream("myNewYesSignalData.txt", FileMode.Create))
        mCont.Data.SaveAsText(dataWithLabel, stream);
}
```

and a similar script for "myNoSignalData.csv" with `output.Label = 0` instead of `output.Label = 1`.